# Regex for string "hh:mm:ss tt"

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

How can I restrict a string to have one of the following values? All are case insensitive:

1. hh:mm:
2. hh:mm:ss
3. hh:mm tt
4. hh:mm:ss tt

I've tried this Regex ^[hh:mm][:ss]?[ tt]?[:ss tt]?$, but it's not giving me desired results. Any help?

Comment: Are you looking for Regex to define Date formats in string?

Comment: Yes, but only Time Formats. I'm using a Third Party control which has a Mask property. Time format is configurable by the user. I just need to pick that time format and provide it to the Mask property of the control. However, in case incorrect format is provided, it will be replaced with the default time format. Hence, to validate provided time format, I need Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you make a confusion between character class`[ab]` and groups `(abc)`.
Have a try with this regex:

```
^(hh:mm)(?::ss)?(?: tt)?$
```

where:

```
^           : begining of string
  (hh:mm)   : capture group that contains 'hh:mm'
  (?::ss)?  : optional non capture group that contains ':ss'
  (?: tt)?  : optional non capture group that contains ' tt'
$           : end of string
```